# How to fetch 2 or more docs if a query matches at least once in the doc?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch. Is there a way to write queries which will match and list out all the documnents which matches certain available fields including the common ones?

I'll try to put this with an example.

I have a system where based on some criteria we give out recommendations. Like a graph. E.g. starting from product, osname, architecture (machine), release, version & so on. I would 1st like to match `product` and `osname` as common for all the search. Later search if architecture is `x86` if true, then add this doc to result & then if release is of `Service Pack 1` then add this again to the result. At the end, result should contain both `3` & `4` docs as both has common fields product and osname and one of the query matches phrase "Service Pack 1" and other matches "x86"

Below are 2 of my recommendations if the query satisfies criteria give back that doc. Below doc has product & osname as common fields.

```
PUT /support/recommendation/3
{
    "recommendation":"Suggested architecture 64 Bit",
    "type":"warning",
    "criteria": {
        "product": ["tar","zip"],
        "osname": "windows",
        "machine": "x86"    
    }   
}
PUT /support/recommendation/4
{
    "recommendation":"Service Pack 2 or more is needed",
    "type":"error",
    "criteria": {
        "product": ["tar","zip"],
        "osname": "windows",
        "release": "Service Pack 1"
    }   
}
```

My query

```
GET /support/recommendation/_search
{   /*search tar, windows, 32bit(x86) & SP1*/
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query": {
                "bool"   : {
                    "must": [
                       {"match": {
                          "product": "tar"
                       }
                       },
                       {"match": {
                          "osname": "Windows"
                       }               
                       }
                    ],
                    "must": [
                       {"match_phrase": {
                          "release": "Service Pack 1"
                       }}
                    ], 
                    "should": [
                       {"match": {  
                          "machine": "x86"
                       }               
                       }
                    ]
                }
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your docs in result if they match EITHER machine: x86 OR release: Service Pack 1, then just use should clause including both.

```
GET /support/recommendation/_search {   /*search tar, windows, 32bit(x86) & SP1*/
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query": {
                "bool"   : {
                    "must": [
                       {"match": {
                          "product": "tar"
                       }
                       },
                       {"match": {
                          "osname": "Windows"
                       }               
                       }
                    ],
                    "should": [
                       {"match": {  
                          "machine": "x86"
                          }               
                       },
                       {"match_phrase": {
                          "release": "Service Pack 1"
                       }
                      }
                    ],
                   "minimum_should_match" : 1
                }
            }            
        }
    } }
```

UPDATE: added `minimum_should_match` clause

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried your query, in that if I change `"machine": "x64"` even then it lists both the docs. But for my result it should not as doc `3` is `x86` and doc `4` does not have this criteria.

Comment: Hm I don't get it. In your question you indicated that both doc 3 and 4 should be returned, because one of them matches the criteria for `machine` and another matches the criteria for `release`? Or do you want something else?

Comment: ah wait, I see now what you mean. Interesting. Try adding `minimum_should_match: 1`?

Comment: great, success with ES :)